# I do not know what is wrong with my code, when I run it a box comes up saying "available java classes" but there are none to choose from

Tags: java, netbeans, io, binary-data

Can anyone see if they can get this to compile, or help me figure out what is wrong? I want to make sure it's not just Netbeans.
The output should look something like this.
Everything seems like it should compile fine, but I'm lost. I've probably been looking at it for too long and overlooking a simple problem.

this is the problemVV
[image]
this is what it should look likeVV
[image]

```
package mp06;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class SalesAgent {

    String first;
    String last;
    double sales;
    Date date;

    public SalesAgent() {
        first = last = null;
        sales = 0;
        date = null;
    }

    public void inputSalesAgent() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Name : ");
        first = s.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name : ");
        last = s.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Sales price : ");
        sales = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Date(Day MMM dd hh:mm:ss STD) : ");
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("Day mmm dd hh:mm:ss zzz");
        try {
            date = df.parse(s.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile(DataOutputStream outstream) {
        try {
            outstream.writeUTF(first);
            outstream.writeUTF(last);
            outstream.writeDouble(sales);
            outstream.writeUTF("" + date);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
    }

    public SalesAgent[] readFromFile(DataInputStream instream) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("Day mmm dd hh:mm:ss zzz");
        SalesAgent sa[] = null;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            while (true) {
                sa[i] = new SalesAgent();
                sa[i].first = instream.readUTF();
                sa[i].last = instream.readUTF();
                sa[i].sales = instream.readDouble();
                sa[i].date = df.parse(instream.readUTF());
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return sa;
    }

    public SalesAgent getSalesAgent() {
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SalesAgent sa = new SalesAgent();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char ch = 'y';
        try {
            DataOutputStream outfile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("salesForce.dat"));
            while (ch != 'n') {
                sa.inputSalesAgent();
                sa.writeToFile(outfile);
                System.out.println("Any more data?");
                ch = s.next().charAt(0);
            }
            outfile.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
    }
}






package mp06;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


// UI program for loading salesForce.dat binary file
// ReadSalesForce.java

public class ReadSalesForce extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel jp1, jp2;
    JLabel lblfile, lblfirst, lbllast, lblsales, lbldate;
    JTextField txtfirst, txtlast, txtsales, txtdate;
    JButton btnprev, btnnext;

    SalesAgent sa[];
    DataInputStream infile;
    int index = 0;

    public ReadSalesForce() {
        setTitle("Cyclical navigation");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        try {
            infile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("salesForce.dat"));
            sa = new SalesAgent().readFromFile(infile); // read from file to array
            infile.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
        // creating labels
        lblfile = new JLabel("salesforce.dat");
        lblfirst = new JLabel("First");
        lbllast = new JLabel("Last");
        lblsales = new JLabel("Sales");
        lbldate = new JLabel("Date");

        // creating text boxes
        txtfirst = new JTextField(20);
        txtlast = new JTextField(20);
        txtsales = new JTextField(20);
        txtdate = new JTextField(20);

        // buttons creation
        btnprev = new JButton("<<");
        btnnext = new JButton(">>");

        // adding components to panel
        jp1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jp1.add(lblfile);
        jp1.add(lblfirst);
        jp1.add(txtfirst);
        jp1.add(lbllast);
        jp1.add(txtlast);
        jp1.add(lblsales);
        jp1.add(txtsales);
        jp1.add(lbldate);
        jp1.add(txtdate);

        // add componets to panel2
        jp2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jp2.add(btnprev);
        jp2.add(btnnext);

        add(jp1, BorderLayout.CENTER); // adding panel to frame
        add(jp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnprev.addActionListener(this); // adding actionlistener interfaces
        btnnext.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) // handling events
    {
        String src = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (src.equals("<<")) {
            if (index < 0) {
                index = sa.length - 1;
            } else {
                index--;
            }
        }
        if (src.equals(">>")) {
            if (index == sa.length) {
                index = 0;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }

        txtfirst.setText(sa[index].first);
        txtlast.setText(sa[index].last);
        txtsales.setText("" + sa[index].sales);
        txtdate.setText("" + sa[index].date);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReadSalesForce rsf = new ReadSalesForce();
        rsf.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        rsf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the exception you are getting when compiling and remove any unnecessary code.

Comment: thats it though... I do not get an error. a box pops up when I try to run it that I would normally click on the class to make it run but for some reason netbeans is not finding my classes

Comment: what code would be unnecessary? I dont know what the problem is So I want you to be able to see it all to see if there is something I'm missing

Comment: Are you getting a classNotFoundException when trying to execute the project in NetBeans? Is NetBeans not displaying your classes on the left panel? Please be clearer.

Comment: I added a picture of what happens when I try to run the program. I can not do anything after that. usually there is a class I can click and it runs.

Comment: Brian, you have to be much clearer in your question. What steps are you performing before getting that NetBeans window? It asks for you to choose a JavaFX Application class but your class extends a JFrame, which is a Swing component. Simply pressing SHIFT+F6 in the  ReadSalesForce tab should execute it and make the desired window display

Comment: when I did SHIFT+F6 the same window pops up. and all I have been doing is clicking the run button on netbeans to run it and that window pops up.

Comment: It seems to be a NetBeans problem, try clearing the cache at C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache and restarting NetBeans.

Comment: ok. so the way I have it now you mentioned swing and FX. should it work the way I have it or did I miss a step converting it?

Comment: You have 2 main methods. Could your IDE be asking you to choose which class contains the main you want to run? Try removing or renaming one of them.

Comment: You can't convert from Swing to JavaFX or vice-versa. I made a new Java Application in NetBeans and added your two classes and it executed fine (though the result was not exactly as the image you posted). SHIFT+F6 only executes the selected file so it should be opening a new Frame as you would expect from the main method - there is nothing wrong in the code, it compiles and executes.